# The derivative of a trigonometric function.

Tags: derivatives

> Let: $$f(x) = \sin x + \frac{\sin3x}3 + \frac{\sin5x}5 +
>  \frac{\sin7x}7$$ Prove that: $$f' \left(\frac{\pi}{9}\right) = \frac{1}{2}$$

Could somebody point me in the right direction with this one?

Comment: the right direction: the derivative of sinx is cosx. Now can you take the derivative of the other three terms? Don't forget chain rule here. You may need some trig identities to work around with that given value of x

Answer (score 3):

$$f'(x)=\cos x+\cos3x+\cos5x+\cos7x$$

Observe that the angles of cosine ratios are in arithmetic progression

So, using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro), we multiply either sides by $\displaystyle2\sin\frac{(3x-x)}2=2\sin x,$

$$2\sin xf'(x)=2\sin x(\cos x+\cos3x+\cos5x+\cos7x)$$

Using $2\sin A\cos B=\sin(A+B)+\sin(A-B)$
$$2\sin xf'(x)=\sin2x+\sin4x-\sin2x+\sin6x-\sin4x+\sin8x-\sin6x=\sin8x$$

If $9x=\pi, 8x=\pi-x\implies \sin8x=\sin(\pi-x)=\sin x\ne0$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: That's very neat indeed. I need to copy that...

Comment: To be honest, I can't really figure out a way forward from there. I would have approached this problem in a different way.

Comment: What exactly should I do with the 2sinx before the derivative?

Comment: @user98079, observe that I have multiplied either sides after derivative, please have a look into the edited version

Comment: I got $$f'(\frac{pi}{9}) = \frac{1}{sin\frac{pi}{9}}$$ but that does not equal 1/2

Comment: @user98079, how, You should get $$f'\left(\frac\pi9\right)=\frac{\sin\frac{8\pi}9}{2\sin\frac\pi9}$$  $$=\frac{\sin\left(\pi-\frac{\pi}9\right)}{2\sin\frac\pi9}=\frac{\sin\frac\pi9}{2\sin\frac\pi9}=\frac12$$ as $\sin(\pi-x)=\sin x$